# Download problem-I don't have disc drive. I press 12 but it doesn't use the USB stick

Tags: usb, downloads

I downloaded the package from ubuntu. When I open the file from the download page, it asks to burn into a disc drive. My computer doesn't have a disc drive. I have an 8GB USB stick attached to the computer. The download instructions say to press the F12 key to burn to the USB stick. I press it and nothing happens. I have a lenovo T440s  running Windows 7 64-bit. Thank you.

Comment: See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows If you still can't do it, edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a software for burning images. I personally used Daemon Tools Pro to burn the ISO downloaded onto my USB stick.

Some people even have no problem only copying the files from the ISO to the USB Stick.

Also when pressing the F12 when asked to, make sure you use Fat32 formatted USB stick.

In case you don't. You can change it simply through "My Computer" right click on USB stick and click "format"